# Why does the <%@ include directive render correctly in IE but not Firefox or Chrome(latest versions)

Tags: html, jsp, include, directive

I'm trying to include a html file using the following syntax:

```
<%@ include file="path/to/file.html" %>
```

But I encounter problems when browsing the page using Firefox(latest) and Chrome(latest) and possibly others which I haven't tested. This include works fine on IE 9 as far as I can see.

Can anyone explain this?

***Note:***

The parent file is index.html and I suspect that that include directive only applies to `*.jsp` files, but I cannot confirm this as I am working in a directory where I have only read permissions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *The parent file is index.html*

Rename it to `index.jsp`. This way the `<%@include%>` will run. It's JSP, not HTML. JSP runs on webserver, not webbrowser. Webbrowser only understands HTML. The interpretation of the -for the webbrowser- unknown `<%@include%>` tag depends on the webbrowser used and is undetermined.